# is it possible to add wildcarts in the redirect_uri in identity server?

Tags: identityserver4, redirect-uri

I'm trying to configure a valid redirectUri for all of my swagger clients, It cost me  a lot of work, cause I have to configure a redirectUri for local environment and one redirectUri for each environment.

I try to add something like * / * or http://* and this is not working.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in #identityserver4 you can add many redirect URLs but domain name and subdomain will be used and port will be ignored:

```
https://for.example.com
https://for.example.com:888
https://for.example.com:999
```

are the same.

Comment: But I need wildcarts to use always the same wildcart something like * .mydomain.com/ *

Comment: as described in:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2
The redirection endpoint URI MUST be an absolute URI

Comment: I don't know why someone will want to make this uri an absolute URI, this make me be carefull with the redirect uri of all of the apps. :(

Comment: They had have to implement it in this way because of rfc (the unique protocol)

Comment: Can you complete your first answer with all the comments?, if you complete the answer I will Accept it as correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: @delfosk9 Redirect URI's must be absolute to mitigate the risks of open redirection.
"An open redirect vulnerability occurs when an application allows a user to control a redirect or forward to another URL. If the app does not validate untrusted user input, an attacker could supply a URL that redirects an unsuspecting victim from a legitimate domain to an attacker’s phishing site."